# Cannot Create or Drop User in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, aws

OK. I have set up a new MySQL Server in AWS Ubuntu EC2 and migrate databases from the RDS. After importing the tables, stored procedures and functions into the new server, I encountered the attached error.
[image]

This happens whenever I want to create or drop users, or if I modify the stored procedure and apply changes. For stored procedures or functions, if I continue to apply changes second time, it would work.

I tried to delete those users in my Workbench but the pop-up error prevents me from doing that.

I think these users were created when I import those stored procedures with those definers.

Anyone could help?
[image]

Comment: did you tried to remove or replace definers (of all in routines) of these users by your root account  and then deleting ..?

Answer (score 1):

Do not import the tables in the database `mysql` from a server running a different version of MySQL.